# VBA Macro, Replace and Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to replace certain cells with a vlookup function.

```
Columns("R").Select
Columns("R").Replace What:="N/A", _
                        Replacement:="=VLOOKUP(RC[-15], [test.xls]test_data'!$C:$R , 16, FALSE)", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

The current code above does not replace the N/A with the vlookup. It just leaves the cell unchanged.

If I removed the "=" in brackets, so it looks like this:

`Replacement:="VLOOKUP(RC[-15], [test.xls]test_data'!$C:$R , 16, FALSE)"`

This does replace my cells, but wont be in a formula format.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the `"N/A"` actually the text in the cell or is it the error `#N/A` or is it text put there by a formula?

Comment: the text in the cell is actually N/A. The current code right now does nothing.

Comment: So what is it doing that it shouldn't? `The below code does not seem to work` is not very descriptive.  Please put the answer to this in the original post using [edit] and not in the comments.

Comment: Try manually typing the formula `=VLOOKUP(RC[-15], [test.xls]test_data'!$C:$R , 16, FALSE)` into one of your cells.  Note that Excel complains about it (partly because of the mix of R1C1 notation and A1 notation, and partly because it is syntactically wrong).  Fix the formula.  Try again.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the edits in original. Essentially it leaves my cells unchanged. As if the replacement code recognizes it as a function.

Comment: That formula is syntactically incorrect.  Manually typing it (or copy/pasting it from the question) won't work.  Once you fix the formula, the only thing you **might** need to know (depending on whether you normally use R1C1 notation or not) are the statements `Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1` and `Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1`.  But the primary issue you have is the invalid formula.

Comment: Would I need to add formulaR1C1 somewhere in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with your formula which is preventing Excel from actually accepting it.  You are trying to use

```
=VLOOKUP(RC[-15], [test.xls]test_data'!$C:$R , 16, FALSE)
```

but that

- has a syntax error, due to the missing quotation mark, i.e. `[test.xls]test_data'` should be `'[test.xls]test_data'`, and
- is mixing R1C1 notation (`RC[-15]`) and A1 notation (`$C:$R`)

The formula you intended to use was probably

```
=VLOOKUP(RC[-15], '[test.xls]test_data'!C3:C18 , 16, FALSE)
```

So you probably meant your code to say

```
Columns("R").Select
Columns("R").Replace What:="N/A", _
                     Replacement:="=VLOOKUP(RC[-15], '[test.xls]test_data'!C3:C18, 16, FALSE)", _
                     LookAt:=xlPart, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     MatchCase:=False, _
                     SearchFormat:=False, _
                     ReplaceFormat:=False
```

---

Now, if your Excel settings are set so that you use R1C1 notation as the default, the correction to your formula is probably all that you will have to change.

But, if you use A1 notation as the default, that formula won't be interpreted correctly due to `C3:C18` being ambiguous as to the notation being used.

So you will possibly need to temporarily set Excel to use R1C1 notation:

```
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
Columns("R").Select
Columns("R").Replace What:="N/A", _
                     Replacement:="=VLOOKUP(RC[-15], '[test.xls]test_data'!C3:C18, 16, FALSE)", _
                     LookAt:=xlPart, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     MatchCase:=False, _
                     SearchFormat:=False, _
                     ReplaceFormat:=False
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
This worked and I understood difference in the annotation formats.

Appreciate everyone's help.